# Aplicación web desarrollada con Visual Studio .NET en C# no depura correctamente

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Buenas tardes,

Estoy retomando una aplicación web desarrollada por un tercero en Visual Studio 2015 con C# en .NET, estoy tratando de levantar la página y volver a colocarla en funcionamiento pero la misma no depura correctamente. Soy totalmente nuevo en este ambiente de desarrollo antes mencionado.

Al depurar el proyecto la lista de errores arroja el siguiente error
[image: Error]

E investigando en foros web me he encontrado con un posible error y es que existen dos web.config
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probé eliminando cada uno de los dos de tal forma que el proyecto no tuviera el archivo duplicado y no solucionó el problema.

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar estaré agradecido. Si existe información que no este explicita con gusto editaré la respuesta!!

Saludos

------------------------------------EDICION---------------------------------------

El proyecto se encuentra agregado dentro del IIS ya que esta aplicación web estuvo operativa en algun momento.

[image: IIS]

**AQUI EL WEB.CONFIG**

```
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="**********" connectionString="*********" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="60"/>
    </authentication>

    <compilation/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

    <!--<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Manage/Error"/>-->



  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="****" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>

</configuration>
```

Comment: No son archivos duplicados, el `Web.Config` que esta arriba se usar para los `Views` el segundo es el archivo de configuracion de la aplicacion, el error debe de ser sobre ese. Si pudieras publicarlo aqui, excluyendo informacion sensible claro (cadenas de conexion u otros datos sensibles)

Comment: No soy un maestro en VisualStudio, pero lo que se es que al tener dos aplicaciones una de las dos debe ser la raiz para trabjar en visual studio, lo que dice Paulo Urbano es correcto, pero es posible que si montas todo el sitin en el servidor IIS defines una aplicación principal y luego las otras le das clic derecho crear aplicación y de esa manera funciona una app dentro de otra.

Comment: @Paulo Urbano Rivera reinicie el VSy cambié la raíz, sin embargo el problema persiste. El manual de usuario de la aplicación dice que el código esta desarrollado en la versión del 2015 y estoy tratando de iniciar la aplicación desde ahí y sigue el error así que no es problema de compatibilidad de versiones (estoy descartando todas las posibles fallas) Cabe destacar que la aplicación ya esta creada en el IIS de Windows como indico en la edicion de la pregunta !! No creo que sea problema con el `web.config` , sin embargo lo publicaré en la edición de la pregunta excluyendo datos de importancia.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, averiguando tu problema pude dar con un error bastante común y que sólo se soluciona abriendo y cerrando Visual Studio... este error consta en que al momento de abrir el proyecto, lo que seleccionaste fue la carpeta "maestra". 
Me explico:

Digamos que tenemos esta estructura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de abrir el proyecto seleccionaste la carpeta `Projects` en desmedro de la carpeta `Blog`, que es la que realmente contiene la aplicación y debería ser tu carpeta raíz, de modo que los diversos `webconfig` que se encuentran dentro de `Blog`, tienen conflictos a nivel de aplicación tomando como punto de partida la carpeta `Projects`.

La solución sería normalmente, cerrar VS y elegir como carpeta raíz, el directorio que contiene el proyecto.